# Is there a general equation expressing the area of a spherical quadrilateral using two polar angles, an azimuth, and a radius?

Tags: surfaces, spherical-geometry

Is there a general equation expressing the area of a spherical quadrilateral using two polar angles, $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$, an azimuth, $\phi$, and a radius, $r$?

I know this can be done by integration, but it seems like there should be an algebraic statement I could build in Excel.

http://wikisend.com/download/576780/Spherical quadrilateral.pdf

Comment: You could post the diagrams to a file sharing site with links and someone could add them here. Regards

Comment: Good idea.  http://wikisend.com/download/576780/Spherical quadrilateral.pdf